# IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, UserInformation>> vs IDictionary<string,UserInformation>

Tags: c#, ienumerable, idictionary

I've a question.
I most recently changed one of my `IDictionary` to a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>`.
This was made because this collection of items shouldn't be modified.
As i can see these are the same but IEnumerable dosn't implement the Add, remove etc, this made this perfect for me and my area of using this collection.

```
public IDictionary<string, UserInformation> MyItems;
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, UserInformation>> MyItems;
```

Now to my questions.

- Is this the smartest way to go if i don't want the collection to be
  modified?
- Is there a smarter way in doing this?
- Am i being stupid doing like this?

I found simular posts to this before but none actually explaining what to use and why.

Comment: IMO this is a bad solution because you lose the key-index, which is the main feature of a dictionary. Regarding read-only dictionaries, please take a look at the solution I've suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11908709/1484750

Comment: You can use `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyDictionary`

Comment: There really isn't enough context to answer this - how do you expect this collection to be used? How is it to be initialized? Who will be using it (you? colleagues? third parties?)? Is this part of a public API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important problem is that an `IDictionary` is designed to be used for efficient lookup. If you *really* only want to represent a sequence of pairs, then your approach is okay - but I wouldn't use `KeyValuePair` unless the relationship is really a key/value semantically... in which case I really would just use a dictionary.

You don't have to *expose* the dictionary, of course - you can expose methods which *only* fetch the value for a key (and perhaps also expose a sequence of keys, and a sequence of values).

Or you could create a read-only implementation of `IDictionary<,>` of course - there's a sample implementation [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1269311/22656).

Comment: For a second I thought that you were going to link my answer =)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll go with the ReadOnly implementation, seems perfect for this collection. I'll also try and change the infrastructure so i don't have to expose the dictionary, this was the beginning of why i even considered using a IEnumerable of KeyValuePair. Thank you! (in the end i can just make it private, and using get to fetch the values)

Comment: "in which case I really would just use a dictionary." - Why? Dictionary has more overhead than a collection of KeyValuePair, so why would you use a dictionary over a set KeyValuePair to just represent a sequence of pairs?

Comment: @BornToCode: Well the "key" part of "key value pair" suggests that it's going to be looked up. If it's really, really only a sequence of pairs (not key/value pairs), then sure, use a sequence - but then don't use `KeyValuePair`, basically as I said in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you can *wrap* your `IDictionary<string, UserInformation>` into some class, with a single `Get(...)` method. Something like this:

```
public class DictionaryWrapper
{
   private IDictionary<string, UserInformation> _dict = .... // dictionary is PRIVATE!

   public UserInformation GetUserInfo(string key)    // method is PUBLIC
   {
      UserInformation ui;
      _dict.TryGetValue(key, out ui);
      return ui;
   }
}
```

In this way you:

- limit acces to the `Dictionary`, and so to its public members too.
- continue to benefit from **O(1) access speed** provided by the dictionary, which you lose when you use `IEnumerable<..>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

By your questions,

1. IEnumerable is a smart way of allowing of implying this is a collection that cannot be modified.
2. There are a number of downsides of changing your return type to that,

   1. `IEnumnerable<KeyValuePair<string, UserInformation>>` can have duplicate keys.  `IDictionary` can't
   2. Although the collection representation if implemented as a Dictionary means you have all of your indexes / buckets etc..., the caller does not know that.  They may create their own dictionary if they need to index things.